# Installing Redmine with apache in localhost slackware 13.1

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, redmine, slackware

I just installed Redmine in slackware 13.1 I followed the instructions and test of the installation works fine using webrick:

```
ruby script/server webrick -e production
```

However, I now want to use it with apache in my local computer (localhost) but no idea how to configure apache for this.

The document root of apache is /var/www/htdocs. So I created a symbolic link to where redmine is (its owned by apache:apache) just to access it by http://localhost/redmine. Now if I access http://localhost/redmine I see the directories but how to run redmine cgi?

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I have used Phusion Passenger to work Redmine in with Apache. Phusion Passenger is the same thing as mod_rails. http://www.modrails.com/

Apache-specific user's guide: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html